# 90's teen horror novel where "Mike" goes on a date with a girl to see their favourite band "The Zombies"

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult, horror

This was a teen horror book from the 90s. It is not *Point Horror*, *Fear Street*, or *Goosebumps*. I am sure the the title was "Bad Blood"; however, I have searched online and can't find it.

The story of what I recall was a guy named "Mike", I think, and he is in high school and is in love with this girl. He wins tickets to a gig for their favourite band (I think they were called "The Zombies") so he asks the girl to go and she agrees.

On the drive to the gig they approach a bridge above them and someone throws a brick at the car and runs away. The date is ruined and Mike (if that is his name) I think persuades her to carry on with the date. They get to the gig only to discover I think that the tickets are fake. The girl after the the events demands to be taken home.

Throughout the book bad things happen to both of them: I think a pet is killed and other friends die, etc. Turns out it is Mike's best friend who is stalking them, as he is jealous.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you remember any fantasy elements to this story?

Comment: Could you describe the cover, please? If possible, draw  a rough approximation of it; questions such as [this one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/203795/102999) have been found by the askers drawing a thing resembling their memories of the cover.

Answer (score 13):

This is *Bad Blood* by Peter Kennedy (1996). It is the fifth book in the "Fun Fax Horror" series. It is young adult, according to Goodreads.

Summary (emphasis mine):

> **Mike** Campbell can't believe his luck: he's got **two free Zombies tickets** and the most popular **girl in his class has agreed to go to the concert with him!** What Mike doesn't realise is that he's just made a deadly date with murder...
>   Should **jealousy** really push anyone this far?
>   <sub>[Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1208737.Bad_Blood)</sub>

---

Found with the query `"bad blood" horror "book"` in Google Search.

Comment: Please accept this answer by hitting the checkmark under the voting buttons to mark this as identified.

Comment: I didn't even realise YA was a demographic that existed in 1996. I'd find this sort of thing under "teen fiction".